# TypeError: must be str, not numpy.int64. Unable To Pinpoint the problem

Tags: python, deep-learning

This particular line:

```py
img = image.load_img('content/gdrive/My Drive/Practice Machine Learning/Test/Images/' +train['Id'][i]+'.jpg', target_size=(400,400,3))
```

is giving me the following error:

"TypeError: must be str, not numpy.int64"

Could you guys please let me where the issue is? I'm quite new to Python.

Comment: Hi, to help others better understand the issue, please always post a minimal reproducible code or provide more context such as what library you are using, what tutorial your are trying to follow, etc. Also more trace back error message can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping `train['Id'][i]` in a `str()` call. This converts the numpy.int64 type to a string so it can be concatenated.

I.e. change:

```
img = image.load_img('content/gdrive/My Drive/Practice Machine Learning/Test/Images/' +train['Id'][i]+'.jpg', target_size=(400,400,3))
```

to

```
img = image.load_img('content/gdrive/My Drive/Practice Machine Learning/Test/Images/' +str(train['Id'][i])+'.jpg', target_size=(400,400,3))
```

Comment: It works. I was getting similar issue while using a numpy array value.